# Sort JSON Output Alphabetically

Tags: html, json, scala, sorting

I am after help on how to write/modify the below code so that my JSON output is sorted alphabetically by the 'Currency' field.

Here is the code that performs the output of the JSON:-

```
  def balance = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    val body = request.body
    (for (
      apiKey <- (body \ "api_key").validate[String]
    ) yield {
      val balances = globals.engineModel.balance(None, Some(apiKey))
      Ok(Json.toJson(balances.map({ c =>
        Json.obj(
          "currency" -> c._1,
          "amount" -> c._2._1.bigDecimal.toPlainString,
          "hold" -> c._2._2.bigDecimal.toPlainString
        )
      })
      ))
    }).getOrElse(
      BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> Messages("messages.api.error.failedtoparseinput")))
    )
  }
```

And the second part of the code is:-

```
    function show_balance(){
        API.balance().success(function(balances){
            for (var i = 0; i < balances.length; i++) {
                balances[i].available = zerosToSpaces(Number(balances[i].amount) - Number(balances[i].hold));
                balances[i].amount = zerosToSpaces(balances[i].amount);
                balances[i].hold = zerosToSpaces(balances[i].hold);
            }
            $('#balance').html(template(balances));
        });
    }
    show_balance();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged JavaScript, but looks more like Scala. Assuming `balance` is a type with a deterministic order (not a `Set`), you should be able to do `balance.sortBy(_._1)`.

Comment: Sorry yes it is scala, are you able to provide more detail about your suggested solution?